# Webextensions API Autocomplete in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm pretty new to java/typescript in general, but I figured a good way to get started would be a firefox plugin. At the moment, I'm following firefox's [second extension tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension) to get familiar with the basics. When entering the javascript for the choose_beast.js file, however, I noticed that anything to do with the browser module, or anything inside of it, was giving me an error saying it's an unresolved module.

Obviously something needs to be imported, but I'm a little stuck on what and how. I found [a post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002583619-Firefox-AddOn-webextension-need-advice-for-Project-IDE-config-maybe-plugins-or-support-libs) on the IntelliJ forums that I believe mentions this issue, but I'm not sure what they mean by adding it as a type. Next stop was youtube, but all of the tutorials for firefox extensions I could find were several years out of date. I resorted to ChatGPT (I know, I know), and it had me download the web-ext package with "npm install -g web-ext" and "npm install --save-dev web-ext", but the package doesn't have anything inside it that exports a browser module.

I'm completely stuck here - not even the Mozilla docs have anything I can find on importing the API, and the example plugins they have don't import it either. How would I go about importing the browser module properly?

Comment: Use [this answer](/a/25466708) with `firefox-webext-browser` instead of `chrome`.